# Is it faster to LIKE 2 columns on 100k records or one column on 200k records?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, database-design, indexing

Suppose I have a table with `column_a` and `column_b`, containing 100k records.
I need to match either `column_a` OR `column_b`.

Will it be faster to create a new table containing only one column to match but twice the records?
Instead of this:

```
table_a

id  column_a  column_b
--  --------  --------
1   foo       bar

SELECT ... WHERE "column_a" LIKE '%blah%' OR "column_b" LIKE '%blah%'
# will iterate through 100k records
```

I'll have this:

```
table_b

id  column
--  ------
1   foo
2   bar

SELECT ... WHERE "column" LIKE '%blah%'
# will iterate through 200k records
```

What is cheaper, text matching or iteration?

Comment: dear downvoters, can you please comment your hard work?

Comment: Not a downvoter, but "Just too lazy to write a test, so will ask here" isn't a good way to start a question.

Comment: Not only is "Just too lazy to write a test, so will ask here..." a terrible way to start a question, but a performance question like this is something you **have to** just try on your own, because there are so many variables that can affect performance.

Comment: I should have phrased that better - I'm guessing the downvotes are for lack of research.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but I would guess it's because of your first line `Just too lazy to write a test, so will ask here... :)`  If you are too lazy, why should they do the work for you?  Sounds like you are perfectly capable to perform the test...

Comment: well, mostly it wanted to mean that somebody already did such a decision after doing same test... :)

Comment: My guess: about the same speed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It also depends on the column types, size of columns, data distribution, other columns in the table and more. I guess you were just too lazy to tell us all those tedious details.

Generally, the fastest way is **`table_b`** with a [trigram GIN index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html) to support the non-anchored `LIKE` expression. The index makes the difference. And the query style will be another important factor. Utilize `LIMIT 1` or `EXISTS` for `table_b`.

More details in this closely related answer:
[PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

I am just too lazy to write a more detailed answer. *Run a test.* :)

Comment: @slivu Note that `GIN` trigram indexes are only supported on very recent PostgreSQL versions, you may need to upgrade. You didn't include your PostgreSQL version so I can't tell you for sure; look at the release notes to see what versions have appropriate support.